# Operation Not Supported on Non-User Columns?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have the following SQL code:

```
# does not work
select count(*), count(distinct p) from 
(select *, rowid as p from elephants)zzz
```

But I get the following error:

```
Operation Not Supported on Non-User Columns
```

The strange thing is that part of this code seems to work just fine:

```
# works without errors
select *, rowid as p from elephants
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error? I tried to use a CAST statement to change the type to integer or varchar ... I also tried to create a CTE and then rename the column to "fool" the computer into thinking that this is a user column ... but I keep getting the same error.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=tables-row-ids-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should trick the optimizer ... so that P no longer refers to ROWID specifically.  Just add +0 to the ROWID value.  A no-op.

```
select count(*), count(distinct p) from 
(select *, rowid+0 as p from elephants)zzz
```